# Count stacking sequences

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, counting

Given a list of stack heights, calculate the number of ways those heights could have been arrived at by stacking blocks one at a time. Shortest code wins.

Test cases:

```
[2, 2] 6
[3,3,3] 1680
[1,5,9,1] 480480
[] 1
[10] 1
[2,2,2,10] 720720
```

Reference Python implementation:

```
def stacking_count(stacks):
     if sum(stacks) == 0:
         return 1
     count = 0
     for i, n in enumerate(stacks):
         if n == 0:
             continue
         stacks[i] -= 1
         count += stacking_count(stacks)
         stacks[i] += 1
     return count
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:sum(f(a[:i]+[a[i]-1]+a[i+1:])for i in range(len(a))if a[i])if sum(a)else 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCoAwDEWvkrGhOpRuBU9SMkRsNVCjVB08fbXw4C3v//O9t0N9a3kqvM8LA4fr2U02HIOQjRyFRkf2t3WBMB8VBEShsq7JlKSGESVDD7v7mjGVK4FrZxW9/7PoB@gQYvsA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
;@S!:/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/aIVjRSv/////RhjqmOpY6hrEA)

-7 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: ...and hence [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9Y8fB2xQCV////RxvqmOpY6hjGAgA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh wait there is a mathematical approach lol

Comment: How about one with only ASCII and what looks almost like a list of emoticons? [;@S!:/](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/aIVjRSv/////RhjqmOpY6hrEA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ooh cool, sure. Thanks!

Comment: Golfier TIO link as well :P